# Google image crawler won't respect my robots.txt entry to not crawl images

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, google-image-search

I was looking for a way to prevent reverse image searching (namely I didn't want for people who had a copy of one of my images to upload it to google and discover where it originated from). I created the following robots.txt file at put it at the root of my blogspot blog:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /hide*.jpg$
Disallow: /hide*.jpeg$
Disallow: /hide*.png$

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /hide*.jpg$
Disallow: /hide*.jpeg$
Disallow: /hide*.png$
```

With it, I was expecting that all jpg and png image files that start with the word `hide` (eg. `hide1023939.jpg`) would not appear in Google Images (or any other search engine). I was inspired by the official documentation [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en&from=35237&rd=2&visit_id=637248864107276800-2904836803) and [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308).

However Google Images keeps showing them, both when reverse searching as well as searching sitewise for any images. I've added many new images since I implemented the robots directives but even these new files get crawled.

As an observation the images on blogspot/blogger.com are hosted on `http://1.bp.blogspot.com/....file.jpg` instead of my own subdomain (`http://domain.blogspot.com`) and I wonder if this is the cause of the issue?
Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As an observation the images on blogspot/blogger.com are hosted on http://1.bp.blogspot.com/....file.jpg instead of my own subdomain (http://domain.blogspot.com) and I wonder if this is the cause of the issue?

That is indeed the cause of the issue. A `robots.txt` file only affects a single subdomain, so it won't affect anything on a different subdomain.

I don't see any option in Blogger to edit `robots` directives for the image subdomain, and if there's no option for that, then I don't believe there's any other way to keep the images from being crawled/indexed. The only solution I can see without moving off of Blogger would be to prevent crawling/indexing of the pages that contain those images (as Google only indexes images that it can find *on web pages*), but it sounds like you want to keep your web pages indexed, so that's probably not a good option.

But maybe there's some clever solution that I'm overlooking.

Comment: thank you @Maximillian, very elucidating! As you have guessed I can't afford for the pages to be non-indexable...